# Edge Data Format

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am trying to find the most efficient way to return data for a network graph which will be constructed with cytoscape js on the front end. I know that the standard way to add edges and nodes is :

```
// can use reference to eles later
var eles = cy.add([
  { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n0' }, position: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
  { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n1' }, position: { x: 200, y: 200 } },
  { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n2' }, position: { x: 300, y: 300 } },
  { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e0', source: 'n0', target: 'n1' } },
  { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e0', source: 'n0', target: 'n2' } }
]);
```

*Taken from their documentation*

I was wondering if there is a way to effectively do the following:

```
// can use reference to eles later
var eles = cy.add([
  { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n0' }, position: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
  { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n1' }, position: { x: 200, y: 200 } },
  { group: 'nodes', data: { id: 'n2' }, position: { x: 300, y: 300 } },
  { group: 'edges', data: { id: 'e0', source: 'n0', target: ['n1', 'n2'] } }
]);
```

This way I can return an adjacency list from the server instead of an edge/node list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intresting format, but unfortunately, this won't work without maybe a new extension.

The thing is, that every element of the graph has to have an id! So when you add an edge to the graph and assign multiple targets, there ought to be 2 id's for every edge.

If you are trying to optimise your cy instance, you can go over [this](http://js.cytoscape.org/#performance) section of the documentation instead.